# Re-render FlatList by sending the refresh signal from another file?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a map with data in a file that contains Base64 image strings. After getting data from the server I want to re-render the FlatList present in  MainScreen. The Map this a static object in another file. So I need a way to trigger the refresh of FlatList after setting the URL with Base64 string in the map.

Edit1:

I have tried keeping my imageMap in state and passed extraData = {this.state.imageMap} it has not rendered.

Edit2:
The code looks like is. ImageMap will be set in another file.

```
import {ImageClass} from './ImageFile'
export class SomeScreen extends React.component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  imageMap: ImageClass.imageMap
};
}
render() {
return(
     <FlatList
       data = {someData}
       extraData = {this.state.imageMap}
     />
  )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `extraData` prop passing the URL as value, once it changes your `FlatList` will rerender.

[Here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata) is a link for the official `FlatList` docs